# Load checked datagridview row to another datagridview in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

- I have a DataGridView1 with data and a checkboxcolumn in the [0]
  position.
- In the form that contains the DataGridView1 with the checkboxes, I
  have a button
- Now, what I need is a way that allows me, after I check the rows I
  want, get the checked rows to another form creating a small
  datagridview with these rows.
- I want to associate this function to the button_click event.

It's all about multiple selection, the basic "import the lines you want to a previous form".

Can anyone help me?
BIG THANK YOU

Comment: Please show your efforts. And read this: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say with your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in YourDgvMain.Rows)
{
  if ((bool)row.Cells[0].Value == true)
  {
    YourOtherDgv.Rows.add(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a bit messy but should work: bind the row id to the checkbox, store the checked values in a collection, query again the datasource with the condition `WHERE [id] IN ([your collection])` and create the second datagridview with the result of the query.

You should specify however what is the source for the gridview and how do you retrieve the data to get a better answer.

Comment: i tought like you, but i can't figure it out in code :\ 
can you give me some example? thank you

Comment: I really need **your** code. Add the aspx code fo the DataGridView and the code for the DataSource, and if there's codebehind add also that one. I can't code for you ;)